# Truncate datetime object pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to truncate the time from my datetime object. My min example looks like this:

```
    date  
 s1  7/26/2018 9:31       
 s2  7/26/2018 9:32      
 s3  7/26/2018 9:33       
 s4  7/26/2018 9:34      
 s5  7/26/2018 9:35       
 s6  7/26/2018 9:36     

data = [{'date': '7/26/2018 9:31'},{'date': '7/26/2018 9:32'}, 
{'date': '7/26/2018 9:33'},{'date': '7/26/2018 9:34'},
{'date': '7/26/2018 9:35'},{'date': '7/26/2018 9:36'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['s1', 's2','s3','s4','s5','s6'])
```

I would like to truncate the time from my datetime object. My goal looks like this:

```
    date  
 s1  7/26/2018       
 s2  7/26/2018       
 s3  7/26/2018        
 s4  7/26/2018       
 s5  7/26/2018        
 s6  7/26/2018
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You simply need:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.date
```

Output:

```
s1    2018-07-26
s2    2018-07-26
s3    2018-07-26
s4    2018-07-26
s5    2018-07-26
s6    2018-07-26
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Comment: This stores the objects as dates too, which is good for further computation. But it is not like your expected output.

Comment: I misspoke about my target output. Any date format is fine for me, I just want to truncate the time. Thank you all for your help

Comment: Note that importing `datetime` is unnecessary for the method to work, as the `dt` accessor is [built in to pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dt-accessor)

Comment: @sacul, thanks. i was not aware of this. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1**:

You can convert to datetime, then use `dt.strftime` to your desired format:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

>>> df
          date
s1  07/26/2018
s2  07/26/2018
s3  07/26/2018
s4  07/26/2018
s5  07/26/2018
s6  07/26/2018
```

**Method 2**:

You can use a regex to extract your desired strings:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].str.extract('(\d+/\d+/\d+)')

>>> df
         date
s1  7/26/2018
s2  7/26/2018
s3  7/26/2018
s4  7/26/2018
s5  7/26/2018
s6  7/26/2018
```

Comment: Fantastic!! Thank you so much sacul!!

Answer (score 2):

You could use str.split too:

#### Method 3:

```
df.date = df.date.str.split().str[0]
```

---

Timings

```
%timeit pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
%timeit df['date'].str.extract('(\d+/\d+/\d+)')
%timeit df.date.str.split().str[0]

976 µs ± 5.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
322 µs ± 5.73 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
192 µs ± 1.41 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Also very nice!!

Comment: Yes it is the fastest. But I prefer using `pd.to_datetime()`